# Generate random values between two set numbers

Tags: matlab, random

My task is to generate 5000 random numbers between -2 and 5 
then count up how many of those values are between 2 and 3
This is what I have so far:

```
randNums=rand(1,5000); %Generate 5000 random values between 0 and 1

randNums=randNums*7-2; %Get those random values to be between -2 and 5
```

I understand that `7*1=7` and `0*7=0` so -2 from each = 7-2, but I do nut fully understand how to apply that again if the numbers were to be between 5,6 or -6 and 1.

Comment: please rephrase your question ... if the numbers are in (0,1) than all of them would be between -2 and 5

Comment: there's a simple function for that: `def howMany(): return 1000`

Comment: I meant to say generate random numbers between -2 and 5 and count up the ones greater than 2 and less than 3

Comment: rand(1,5000) will generate 5000 random numbers BETWEEN 0-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## My problem interpretation

You have random numbers in the interval (0,1). But you require random numbers in (a,b).

## Solution

You simply have to scale and shift your interval.

**Scale the interval:**
The size/length of the interval (a,b) is b-a. To rescale the interval you have to multiply all your random values with b-a.

**Shift the interval:**
When you have scaled the interval you have numbers in the interval (0,b-a). You simply shift all numbers by adding the number a to it. Which leads to random numbers in the interval (a,b).

Comment: Ok so for instance lets say I was to generate 1000 random numbers form 4 to 7 then count up the ones greater than 5 and less than 6 the code would be....                                                               randNums=rand(1,5000); %Generate 5000 random values between 4 and 7

randNums=randNums*1+5; %Get those random values to be between 5 and 6                                                                                                                                        is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

What you are referring to is called "[Linear Interpolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation)". In some libraries it is called `lerp` and usually it's implemented

```
float lerp(float v0, float v1, float t) {
    return v0+(v1-v0)*t
}
```

So in your case `v0` is -2, `v1` is 7 and `t` is the value between 0 and 1 you want to interpolate.

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = random('unif', -2, 5, 1, 1000);
count = sum(numbers > 2 & numbers < 3);
```

Comment: I had problems with this only in `Octave`, it has been always worked in Matlab. Yo may write 'unif' or 'Uniform' to get uniform distribution

Comment: This makes sense, but we are suppose to use an if statment for the count= part