# Fill a matrix with random values between (-1,1)

Tags: matlab, random

I'm new to matlab and trying to learn how to simulate random numbers.

Is there a simple way to create a `10x20` array filled with random numbers from the uniform `(-1,1)` distribution.

I've seen the rand function, but I'm not sure how to change the uniform `(0,1)` distribution to `(-1,1)`.

Comment: Well, you could multiply the result by two and subtract one from it, although that would give you less randomness.

Comment: @Majora320 Why would it give less randomness? That is the accepted method to create the distribution, right?

Comment: Duplicate of [Matlab, matrix containing random numbers within specified range](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14482951/), some other relevant duplicate targets: [***1***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5077800/), ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ [***2***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27263762/), ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ [***3***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15411585/), ‍‍‍‍‍‍ ‍‍ and the [***official doc***](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/floating-point-numbers-within-specific-range.html)

Comment: @ammportal Let's say we have a distribution from 0 to 5: [0 1 2 3 4 5]. Each of these has an equal chance of being selected. If we extend that to 0 to 11, only some will be selected: [**0** 1 **2** 3 **4** 5 **6** 7 **8** 9 **10** 11]. Obviously, a floating point range will have much more than just  6 different values but the same principle applies.

Comment: @Majora320 Yes, but this is true only for a discrete distribution as in your example. A continuous one does not have this limitation. Although you can't say that all the values between 0 and 1 are generated by MATLAB, the number of values are still sufficient though to have little or no effect on the randomness

Comment: @ammportal I suppose it is insignificant in practice, but precision is limited by, well, floating-point precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually CAN just deform interval of (0,1) using different math operations and still get uniform distribution.

So you have to go this way:

```
result = rand(10,20).*2-1
```

To check is it really still uniform lets do the next:

```
res = rand(10000).*2-1;
histogram(res)
```

As you can see it is still uniform.

[image]

There are some tricks about random numbers (actually it's pseudorandom) and you can get the same 'random' results after restart MATLAB. read about this [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/why-do-random-numbers-repeat-after-startup.html) and [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rng.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula given in Matlab `rand` documentation to achieve random numbers between any interval of numbers:

```
r = a + (b-a).*rand(N,1)
```

In your case for `(-1,1)` interval and an array sized `(10,20)` it should be:

```
r = -1 + (1+1).*rand(10,20)
```

References:
[rand Matlab official documentation](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html)